# Expectation of a stopping time uniquely determined by a function

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Markov chain on a finite state space $\Omega$, with transition probability $P$. Let $T$ be a stopping time such that $T=\min \{t\ge 0;X_t \in A \subset \Omega \}$. 
If $f(x)=E_x(T)$ is such that

$$f(x)=0, x \in A$$
$$f(x)= 1+\sum_{y \in \Omega }P(x,y)f(y), x \notin A$$

How can I show that $f$ is uniquely determined by the previous equation?

I'm not clear on what I have to prove here.

I guess the proof goes as: Suppose $\exists g \ni g \ne f$ and $g(x)=E_x(T)$.

But I don't see any sense here.

Comment: Could you give some more information about $X$? Seems that it is in a discrete time and the state space is $\mathbb Z_+$ but some details from your side will help understanding it. Is it Markov?

Comment: Yes, the process is Markov on a finite state space. I though this information doesn't change the spirit of the proof. Sorry, if it does.

Comment: On more silly question: which stopping time is $T$? There are lots of them, certainly with different expected values.

Comment: There is something fishy here: if $(f(x))_x$ solves your relations and if $f\ge0$ everywhere, then using $f\ge0$ in the RHS yields $f\ge1$ everywhere, hence using $f\ge1$ in the RHS yields $f\ge2$ everywhere, and so on, hence $f$ is identically $+\infty$. Looks like you did not copy faithfully the source you are taking this from.

Comment: @Nicolas There is the germ of a reasonable question here, but you really have to put more effort into your post. For instance, the equation $f(x)=E(T)$ has a variable $x$ on the left but not on the right. Did you really want a constant function? Also, in your equation did you really want to condition on $X_0\neq 0$? Are you possibly leaving out important information like boundary values?? If you  take some time to make your question more precise, then you will get better answers.

Comment: What is "$x$"??

Comment: When $T$ is the first hitting time of a subset $A$ of the state space $S$ by a Markov chain $(X_t)_t$ on $S$, one usually defines $f(x)=E_x(T)$ for every $x$ in $S$ (hence $f=0$ on $A$). Then $f(x)=1+\sum_yq(x,y)f(y)$ for every $x$ **not in $A$**, where $q(x,y)=P(X_1=y\mid X_0=x)$. You could say if this is the (classical) setting you have in mind.

Comment: Yes this is the settings, I have in mind. Sorry, for the confusion. Please, let me edit the question, before any other post. Everybody input made me understand my wrong. Byron, thanks for the wake up call.

Comment: I've edited the question. I think it's better, if ever it's not, be merciless. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so let us put the equation in the one line:
$$
f(x) = 1_{A^c}(x)+1_{A^c}(x)\sum\limits_{y\in \Omega}P(x,y)f(y).\quad (1)
$$
Here $1_{A^c}(x)$ is an indicator function of $A^c = \Omega\setminus A$. I.e. $1_{A^c}(x) = 1$ for $x\in A^c$ and $1_{A^c}(x) = 0$ for $x\in A$. Let us consider now the homogeneous version of the very same equation (which I happened to investigate in my first post):
$$
g(x) = 1_{A^c}(x)\sum\limits_{y\in \Omega}P(x,y)g(y). \quad(2)
$$

Note again that the equation is linear so the solutions of these equations built the linear space. Of course, $g^* = 0$ is a solution of (2). In the simplest case when $A^c$ is finite, an equation (2) has a unique *bounded* solution iff $A^c$ does not have absorbing subsets since $g(x)$ is a probability that $x$ will never leave $A^c$.

Of course it's iff the determinant of $P'$ which is build only by rows and columns from $A^c$ is non-zero. This led me to the idea that non-uniqueness of (1) in this case depends only on the absorbing subsets of $A$. About existence of solution for (1) we 'may not care' since there is at least one function which admits this equation, namely $f(x)=\mathsf E_x[T_A]$. On the other hand, such function takes values from the extended real line for which case uniqueness of the solution is unclear for me.

Consider again the previous example. Let $P$ be a unit matrix of dimension two, so
$p(1,1) = 1$, $p(1,2) = 0$ and $p(2,1) = 0, p(2,2) = 1$. Let us solve it for $A = \{1\}$. If you write your equation for this case you will have $f(1) = 0$ and $f(2) = 1+f(2)$, so the solution of the latter equation is either $-\infty$ or $\infty$ though I am not so experienced in solution of such equations. Well, you can say that the solution is unique if you are looking only for non-negative solutions.

The point is the following: theory of uniqueness for such equations based on fact that solutions build up the vector space. Hence, for any solution $f^*$ of (1) and non-zero solution $g^*$ of (2) you can claim that $f^*+\alpha g^*$ is a solution of (1) which is different than $f^*$. On the other hand, if $f^*$ take infinite values then $f^*+\alpha g^*$ can coincide (at least in symbols) with $f^*$.

Let us consider arbitrary $A^c$. What does mean that (2) has a non-zero solution? The invariance probability is the maximal solution of (2) which lies in $[0,1]$. Let us denote it by $g^*$. So, for each point in which $g^*>0$ it holds that $\mathsf E_x[T_A] = \infty$ (is it clear?). For such points, $f^* = \infty$ and hence $f^*(x)+\alpha g^*(x) =\infty = f^*(x)$, though this statement is quite informal for me.

I cannot give you a complete formal answer to your question since I was always looking only for bounded solutions of such equations. The latter paragraph gives a guess that the solution is indeed unique since non-uniqueness of solution of (2) will appear only in points where $f^*$ is infinite and hence will not influence $f^*$. On the other hand, I didn't consider the case when (2) may have unbounded solution. E.g. by Lebesgue's convention $0\cdot\infty = 0$ so one can say that $g = 1_{A^c}\cdot\infty$ admits (2), if for any $x\in A^c$ there is a transition to $A^c$, as well as $g=0$.

Anyway, I think you need a person more experienced in solving linear equations with unbounded solutions. the other advise is the following - if you want to calculate the solution, you will certainly need to cut-off points in which $\mathsf E_x[T_A] = \infty$. So you will have something like
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}0,&\text{ if }x\in A,
\\
\infty,&\text{ if }x\in B
\\
1+\sum\limits_{y\in\Omega}P(x,y)f(y), &\text{ if }x\in (A\cup B)^c
\end{cases}
$$

I haven't deal with the problem of the average hitting time, so maybe there are smarter ways to solve it. Regards.

Comment: I want to be sure, I understand your answer.

You first solve the homogeneous system 

$$
f(x) = 1_{A^c}(x)\sum\limits_{y\in \Omega}P(x,y)f(y).
$$

Since the solution is not unique if there is an absorbing state, then the solution to the nonhomegous system is not uniquely determined. Did I understand correctly?

Is it right to then infer that, if there is no absorbing state, showing that the solution is unique, amount to show that the homogenous system have a unique solution. That is it's determinant is different than zero.

Comment: Nicolas: beware that the first equation written in this post is not the same as yours and does not correspond to $f(x)=E_x(T)$.

Comment: I think Gortaur answer is applicable to my revised post. The equation he states at the beginning of his post is the same as mine except for the constant term $1$.

Comment: Nicolas: *the same as [yours] except for the constant term 1*... which makes all the difference! Maybe you do not realize this but in most cases (irreducible chain, nonempty $A$) the only solution to the equation written in this post is $f=0$ everywhere. Thus this tells you nothing about the rather different function $f(x)=E_x(T)$ you said you were interested in.

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton: My first answer was incorrect since I misunderstood the equation in your question. I apologize. I fixed it - so it may be not a complete answer, but rather some ideas on this topic. You may think of dis-accepting it, which may encourage other members to contribute - there should be people more familiar with the problem, or more experienced in arithmetic of infinities.

Comment: Gortaur, the precision you had are more than I expected.
Some points are still unclear, but your input links the concepts in my head. Something, I could not have achieve alone, thank you.
I too can't really elaborate on the unclear points. But now, I can analyse this type of settings with linear algebra.
For me, your answer is sufficient, I will keep it as accepted. Thanks again.

Comment: Nicolas, you're welcome, but the reason why I suggested you to dis-accept is that there are members much more experienced in Markov Processes. Didier has already written some points though not a full answer. @Byron: may I ask you to take a look at the question? Maybe you can help OP.

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton: here is some lecture notes with a least-solution characterization of the mean hitting time: http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/s13.pdf Such a characterization widely used in this kind of problems due to the non-unique solution. May be worth for you to read it.

Comment: Gortaur: Thanks for the lectures notes, I read them.
The notes explain that, in the general case, the solution is not unique. I've then infer that in the irreducible case, the solution is unique, though it's not outline in the notes. I will post my  proof.
I'm a bit embarassed to post it, since it's not has clever as your linear algebra analysis of the problem. But, your comments gave some courage. Thanks.
@Byron: if you want to contribute to this post, please let me post the proof first.

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton: that will be interesting, so please put it here.

Answer (score 1):

For the general case, the solution to

$$f(x)=0, x \in A \tag{1}$$
$$f(x)= 1+\sum_{y \in \Omega }P(x,y)f(y), x \notin A$$

is not unique. The probabilistic meaningfull solution is then given by the least nonnegative solution to the system. As explain in the document pointed by Gortaur http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/s13.pdf.

If $P$ is irreducible, we can show the solution is unique as follow.
Suppose $g$ is another solution to the system then $g \ne f$ and

$$g(x)=0, x \in A \tag{2}$$
$$g(x)= 1+\sum_{y \in \Omega }P(x,y)g(y), x \notin A$$

Susbtracting $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have

$$f(x)-g(x)=0, x \in A \tag{3}$$
$$f(x)-g(x)= \sum_{y \in \Omega }P(x,y)(f(y)-g(y)), x \notin A \tag{4}$$

By $(4)$, $f-g$ is harmonic for $P$ on $A^c=\Omega-A$.
If $f-g$ is constant then by $(3)$, $f-g$ is identically zero and $f=g$, which is a contracdiction.
Suppose $f-g$ is not constant. Since $f-g$ is harmonic on $A^c$ then it must attain its maximum and minimum value in $A$, by $(5)$ below. Hence, by $(3)$, $f-g$ is identically zero, which is a contradiction.

$(5)$: Maximum principle: Suppose $P$ is the transition matrix of an irreducible Markov chain, with finite state space $\Omega$. If $h$ is not constant and harmonic on $A\subset \Omega$, then $h$ achieves its maximum in $A^c$.
A similar claim hold for the minimum of $h$.

Comment: Before you obtained (4), did you show that $f,g$ are finite on $A^c$?

Comment: @Gortaur: no, I assume that $f$ and $g$ are finite on $A^c$. I think this is the case, if all state of $A^c$ communicate, that is $A^c$ has no absorbing state. But I'm not sure.